# Nesting Multiple NOT statements with AND and IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to nest multiple if-statements with a few parameters each, most of which I've solved, except for one last IF statement checking two cell values.

| Column A | Rate 1 | Rate 2 | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Free |  |  | Free |
|  | .025 |  | 7 |
|  |  | 15 | 1 |
|  | .055 | 20 | 4 |

The Four Needed Arguments:

- blank rate1 & blank rate2 = "free"
- rate1 has any value, blank rate2 = 7
- blank rate1, rate2 has any value = 1
- rate1 has any value, rate2 has any value = 4

So far, my IF statement(s) look like this:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B1),ISBLANK(C1)),"Free",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),ISBLANK(C1)),"7",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),ISBLANK(B1)),"1",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),"4", <--- the problem
))))
```

However, the last statement does not work. I am unsure if it is impossible to nest two NOT-ISBLANK statements within an AND, within an IF; others more familiar with excel syntax might have better luck. Thoughts on how to make the last statement work properly?

EDIT: The answer was staring me in the face the whole time. For those interested,

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B18)),ISBLANK(C18)),"7",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C18)),ISBLANK(B18)),"1",
IF(AND(ISBLANK(B18),ISBLANK(C18)),"Free","4")))
```

works as I intended. Thanks everyone!

Comment: So what is the role of `Column A` here it shows `Free` in the first cell? And what do you get when both cells `B1` & `C1` are not blank? Found this one working `=IF(AND(B2="",C2=""),"Free",IF(AND(B2<>"",C2=""),7,IF(AND(B2="",C2<>""),1,4)))` don't use `ISBLANK()` function it should have been named as `ISEMPTY()` instead use `""` or you can try `=IFS(AND(B2="",C2=""),"Free",AND(B2<>"",C2=""),7,AND(B2="",C2<>""),1,AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),4)`

Comment: Gotcha you have a typo in your formula : `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2)),"Free",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISBLANK(C2)),7,
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),ISBLANK(B2)),1,
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),NOT(ISBLANK(C2))),4,""))))` -- the `last closing parentheses` for `AND()` was **missing** also **don't** use `numbers` within `quotes` it denotes as **text** unless you don't want to use them for further **calculations**

Comment: Glad it worked for you, you can post your solution in the answers and accept the same to close the post.